# Meaning of "That sort of says something"

Tags: popular-refrains

What does "That sort of says something" mean? What says what?

One man tells another:

> He used to say when his wife died it killed the whole family.
>   *That sort of says something, sir*. That you kept yours together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**That a situation says something about some person**: it reveals something about it or the person involved in it. This is an idiomatic expression.

If I say: "I really hate John Smith supporters." That sentence reveals something about me (me is the person writing this answer). It says something about me. It characterizes something about me.

It reveals or says that: I have no patience or that I waste my energy on hating people. Etc. Etc. Etc.

**Sort of** is just colloquial usage as in: He sort of likes her.

Sort of or kind of are just used adverbially in speech to emphasize a verb.

- That really says something about you. compare:
- That kind of or sort of says something about you.